# Catalog price rule with no effect although it is active and catalogrule_product_price shows correct entries - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules

We have a Magento 1.9.2.1 shop where catalog price rules have no effect at all. The shop consists of two websites and has multiple customer groups. We tried to set up catalog price rules for one or both websites, for one or all customer groups and with or without conditions. Obviously we also applied them and even reindexed all indexes.
Always with the same unpleasant outcome: Regardless if a guest or logged in customer is using the store the rule has none effect in the frontend.

When we look up any product ID in the `catalogrule_product_price` table in the DB we do find the price rule ID there for all websites and customer IDs with the expected (so correctly discounted) prices. `getMatchingProductIds()` and `getData()` of the corresponding rule also returns the expected data we couldn't find anything unusual looking in it.

We do use a couple of extensions but none should hook into the price calculation. We never used catalog price rules before in this shop so we wouldn't know if it has worked at some point.

We are a little bit out of ideas and have followed all obvious tips regarding this topic so any further tips how something like that can be troubleshooted better would be appreciated very much!

Comment: Did you applied it ... i mean did you clicked the apply rule button on top

Comment: I have and from my understanding (also I'm not entirely sure) the `catalogrule_product_price` table gets filled on apply. So we wouldn't see correct entries here when apply wouldn't have worked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What solved the problem was to create a new rule with no customer restrictions and conditions (we also created a start and end date) which gave a global discount for everyone (also this discount was 0%). After that all previously created rules which have restrictions and or conditions instantly also worked correctly. Disabling the global rule was no problem then.

We found that out by excessive trial and error in a test environment and it was reproducible. No idea though what the actual problem is/was.

**Update**
When the 0% rule with no conditions and restrictions is deactivated and new rules with conditions/restrictions get created we again run into the problem that no rule (also none of the old ones) has effect anymore. Re-enabling and applying the 0% rule 'fixed' that again. However this is still strange and a quite ugly workaround so any better ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and found out that for some reason, tax classes for customer groups affected the catalog rules. Please see my answer on here to check it out.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629859/magento-customer-group-catalog-rule-error-in-1-9-0